# AngularJS Current Time

Tags: angularjs, time, current-time

How can i add current time in my project ?
my controller and modul:

```
var app = angular
    .module("persModul", [])
    .controller("persController", function($scope, $http)
```

Comment: Can you post your html where you want to show current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use new Date() and bind on the HTML

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module("persModul", [])
app.controller("persController", function($scope){
      $scope.timeNow = new Date();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="persModul" ng-controller="persController">
  {{timeNow  | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}
</body>
```

**UPDATED DEMO**

```js
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  var tick = function() {
    $scope.clock = Date.now();
  }
  tick();
  $interval(tick, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='TimeCtrl'>
    <p>{{ clock | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want just clock and always updated.For example 10:06:57 / 10:06:58 / 10:06:59 / 10:07:00 ...

Comment: @BALDİ check the updated demo

Comment: I see this  : TİME:{{ clock | date:'HH:mm:ss'}} and my data gone :/

Comment: dude , the demo shows clearly

Comment: yeah, but i didnt understand problem.thnx im working on it

Comment: cool, mark if this helped

Answer (score 0):

You can set interval on one second to get updated time like following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

<p>Current Date & Time = {{ currentDateTime | date:'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    var getCurrentDate = function(){
     $scope.currentDateTime = new Date();
    }
    $interval(getCurrentDate, 1000);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```